# Visitor identification for native mobile apps and Sitecore LayoutServices?

Tags: layout-service

Currently, I am using Sitecore Layout Services to expose Sitecore content to Mobile Native applications. Whenever I am making a request to the Layout Service using Postman, My analytics cookie is always returned with ending value False.

something like `SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE=5d3b52ed7987481c95b684d6bcbf6e40|False`

It does mean that Sitecore identified this request from Robot. I understand that for any client applications frameworks, we do have something like to include `<sc:VisitorIdentification runat="server" />` for MVC and `VisitorIdentification.js` for JavaScript.

Is there something similar in Layout Services for Native mobile application?

Comment: Could you explain what do you want to achieve? Do you need to identify your contact? Or what?

Comment: Contact is already been identified. I just wanted to Sitecore should not classify this contact as a robot.